# How to read a text file for particular kind of data?

Tags: java, file, while-loop, bufferedreader

I have special scenario, in which I am trying to read a file in two while loops . in second loop it reads the file from egining, but I want to read the file where the first while stops reading the file.

Here is my code stuff:

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.startsWith(rootId.trim())) {
        break;
    }
}

while (!(line = br.readLine()).contains("---------------------------------------------------")) {
    // my other code stuff 
}
```

Here my file stores data as follow,

```
-----------------------------------------------------
00001#            // this is the rootId
N1
N2
-----------------------------------------------------
00002#
N1
N2
-----------------------------------------------------
00003#
N1
N2
```

This method takes `rootId` and displays Nodes(N1,N2)  and my other stuff. Here my stratergy is to read the file untill I get the `rootId` after that in another loop untill I get a line (--------) doing my stuff. but in next loop it again starts reading the file from begining . How to solve this. can any help me in this.

Comment: this code looks fine.  Are you showing us the real picture?

Comment: both line i.e. in file vs in your code, number of dashes doesnt match.

Comment: @almasshaikh yes I replaced it with contains("-------")

Comment: As @ScaryWombat said apart from my above comment, nothing looks wrong. So if this is real code it should work.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Second while loop again starts reading frm first.

Comment: yes guys it will work perfect . I was passing wrong `rootId`. So it was showing some abnormal output.

Comment: better delete this question then.

Answer (score 0):

```
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        if(line.startsWith(rootId.trim()))
        {
               break;
        }

        if(!(line = br.readLine()).contains("---------------------------------------------------")) 
        {

            // my other code stuff 


        }

    }
```

All of your code should be in a single loop, try like this and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need two loops - you should be able to process your file line by line using the first loop and then using if- statements

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        if(line.startsWith(rootId.trim())||(line.contains("----"))
        {
               continue;
        }
        //Process your nodes here - add more if statements if necessary
    }
```

Note that you need

```
continue;
```

rather than

```
break;
```